# How to login with Google Account from my PHP application?

Tags: php, html, authentication, web

I need your help. I have been create a PHP application and it has Sign In authentication to access it. My user table  is like this :

```
===========================================================
username | password |        email      |     e_pass
===========================================================
admin    | admin    | mymail@google.com | myGooglePassword
===========================================================
```

Username and password column are for local authentication, then email and e_pass are for Google authentication. So, how can I do that? Both local and Google authentication is done at the same step? Because Google Calendar and Google Drive are embedded in my PHP application and need Google Authentication to access them.

Here my authentication code with PHP code :

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['userid']) or empty($_POST['passwd'])) { // jika file diakses secara langsung ?>
               <script type="text/javascript">
                 alert("You can't access this file directly!");
               </script>";
               <script> document.location.href='index.php'; </script>
<?php   
}
else {
    include "conn.php";
    $user = $_POST['userid'];
    $pass = sha1($_POST['passwd']);

    $sql = mysql_query("select * from access where username = '$user'") or die (mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if ($num <> 0) { // jika username ditemukan dalam tabel access
        $sql = mysql_query("select * from access where password = '$pass'") or die (mysql_error());
        $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);

        if ($num <> 0) { // jika password ditemukan dalam table access
            $sql = mysql_query("select * from access where username = '$user' and password = '$pass'") or die (mysql_error());
            $data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

            // Google Authentication Code supposed to be here

            if ($data['unit'] == 'operational') { // jika unit operational
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
                $_SESSION['unit'] = $data['unit'];
                $_SESSION['sub'] = $data['subunit'];

                if ($data['subunit'] == 'manager') { // jika berstatus manager ?>
                    <script>document.location.href='operational/manager/operational_manager.php?page=home';</script>
                    <?php
                }
                else if ($data['subunit'] == 'facility') { ?>
                    <script>document.location.href='operational/facility/facility.php?page=home';</script>
                    <?php
                }
                else if ($data['subunit'] == 'transport') { ?>
                    <script>document.location.href='operational/transportation/transport.php?page=home';</script>
                    <?php
                }
                else if ($data['subunit'] == 'procure') { ?>
                    <script>document.location.href='operational/procurement/procure.php?page=home';</script>
                    <?php
                }
                else if ($data['subunit'] == 'it') { ?>
                    <script>document.location.href='operational/it/it.php?page=home';</script>
                    <?php   
                }
                else if ($data['subunit'] == 'accounting') { ?>
                    <script>document.location.href='operational/accounting/account.php?page=home';</script>
                    <?php   
                }
            }
            else if ($data['unit'] == 'academic') { // jika unit academic
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
                $_SESSION['unit'] = $data['unit'];
                $_SESSION['sub'] = $data['subunit'];

                if ($data['subunit'] == 'manager') { // jika berstatus manager ?>
                    <script>document.location.href='academic/manager/academic_manager.php?page=home';</script>
                    <?php
                }
                else { ?>
                    <script>document.location.href='academic/academic.php?page=home';</script>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            else if ($data['unit'] == 'bisdev') { // jika unit bisdev
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
                $_SESSION['unit'] = $data['unit'];
                $_SESSION['sub'] = $data['subunit'];

                if ($data['subunit'] == 'manager') { // jika berstatus manager ?>
                    <script>document.location.href='bisdev/manager/bisdev_manager.php?page=home';</script>
                    <?php
                }
                else { ?>
                    <script>document.location.href='bisdev/bisdev.php?page=home';</script>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            else if ($data['unit'] == 'admin') { // jika admin
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
                $_SESSION['unit'] = $data['unit'];
                $_SESSION['sub'] = $data['subunit'];

                ?>
                    <script>document.location.href='admin/admin.php?page=home';</script>
                <?php
            }
            else if ($data['unit'] == 'director') { // jika director
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
                $_SESSION['unit'] = $data['unit'];
                $_SESSION['sub'] = $data['subunit'];

                ?>
                    <script>document.location.href='director/director.php?page=home';</script>
                <?php
            }
        }
        else if ($num == 0){ // jika password tidak ditemukan dalam table access
            ?>
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                     alert("Incorrect password!");
                   </script>";
                   <script> document.location.href='index.php'; </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else if($num == 0) { // jika username tidak ditemukan dalam tabel access
        ?>
               <script type="text/javascript">
                 alert("Username is not registered!");
               </script>";
               <script> document.location.href='index.php'; </script>
        <?php   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: So you have in plain text both the password for your site _and_ for google??

Comment: You should be using Google's OAuth implementation to get an access token, not storing a username/password. Eep.

Comment: Because I thought it has same way like send an email (Gmail) with PHP.

Comment: try to implements this https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the email and password directly. You should use OAuth 2.0. You can learn more about OAuth [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login).

You should store user's access token instead of email id's password.

Comment: Might I have to learn about this because this is something new to me. Thank you so much.